# SelectedItem of ListBox with DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, selecteditem

I have a ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="lbsfHolder" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding UISupportingFunctions}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSupportedFunction, Mode=TwoWay}"
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:SupportingFunction GotFocus="SupportingFunction_GotFocus"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the ViewModel I have:

```
private SupportingFunction _selectedSupportedFunction;

public SupportingFunction SelectedSupportedFunction
{
    get { return _selectedSupportedFunction; }
    set
    {
        _selectedSupportedFunction = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSupportedFunction");
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to select any item in list box nothing happens. The SelectedItem is null for the ListBox and for SelectedValue, too.  Do I need to add some special code to make this work?

**UPD:**

I've changed views a bit, now I have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RFM.UI.WPF.Controls.SupportingFunction">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="supportingFunctions"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding UISupportingFunctions}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSupportedFunction, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBox Name="tbsfName" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                                    <TextBox Name="tbsfExperssion" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Expression}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBox>
                                    <Button Name="bsfDel" Grid.Column="2">Del</Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In Page where this control placed:

```
<StackPanel Name="spSupportingFunctions">
            <StackPanel Name="spsfOperations" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Name="bsfAdd" Width="30" Command="commands:CustomCommands.AddSupportingFunction">Add</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <controls:SupportingFunction DataContext="{Binding Self}" />                
        </StackPanel>
```

at code behind of this Page

```
public PlotDataPage()
    {
        DataContext = new PlotDataViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
```

and this is the full listing of PlotDataViewModel

```
public class UISupportingFunction : ISupportingFunction
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Expression { get; set; }
}

public class PlotDataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PlotDataViewModel Self
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<UISupportingFunction> _supportingFunctions;
    public ObservableCollection<UISupportingFunction> UISupportingFunctions
    {
        get
        {
            return _supportingFunctions;
        }
        set
        {
            _supportingFunctions = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UISupportingFunctions");
        }
    }       

    private UISupportingFunction _selectedSupportedFunction;
    public UISupportingFunction SelectedSupportedFunction
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedSupportedFunction;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedSupportedFunction = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSupportedFunction");
        }
    }

    public PlotDataViewModel()
    {
        UISupportingFunctions = new ObservableCollection<UISupportingFunction>();           
    }

    public void CreateNewSupportingFunction()
    {
        UISupportingFunctions.Add(new UISupportingFunction() { Title = Utils.GetNextFunctionName() });
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
}
```

I'm just calling the CreateNewSupportingFunction() method when I click Add button. Everything looks fine - the items is add and I see them. But when I'm clicking on one of the TextBoxes and then to the bsfDel button right to each item I'm getting null in SelectedSupportedFunction.

Maybe it is because of focus event have been handling by TextBox and not by ListBox?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is exactly, but if SupportingFunction is a control, it shouldn't be in your ViewModel...

Comment: What is your UISupportingFunctions?

Comment: It seems like you didn`t set DataContext for control

Comment: You can also try removing the selection mode. Multiple means selection should be a collection, but your selected property is just one object, not a collection. (note that binding multiple selections to a collection is itself a tricky one).

Comment: Show your property UISupportingFunctions.  Where to you bind controls:SupportingFunction path to a Property?

Comment: Please, look at edited part of question

Answer (score 0):

It's either your ItemsSource UISupportingFunctions is not a SupportingFunction object or you did not set the View's Datacontext to your ViewModel.

ViewModel.xaml.cs

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModelClass();
```